# Java show error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, graph-theory, subgraph

I download [Parsemis](https://www2.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/EN/research/zold/ParSeMiS/index.html) program. It is frequent subgraph mining program create from java. My data for use in parsemis is very big.

I try to run java parsemis in Windows10 by add **-Xmx4096M** it show error like this. What's the cause of this problem? How to fix it ?

```
java -Xmx4096M -jar parsemis-2008-12-01.jar --graphFile=graph_all.lg --outputFile=output.lg --minimumFrequency=10%
```

It show error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at de.parsemis.graph.HPListGraph.<init>(HPListGraph.java:207)
        at de.parsemis.graph.HPListGraph.clone(HPListGraph.java:378)
        at de.parsemis.graph.HPListGraph.clone(HPListGraph.java:41)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.RightMostExtension.add(RightMostExtension.java:110)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.RightMostExtension.extend(RightMostExtension.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.RightMostExtension.call(RightMostExtension.java:150)
        at de.parsemis.miner.chain.GenerationStep.call(GenerationStep.java:94)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.call(GSpanGeneration.java:101)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:210)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:187)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
        at de.parsemis.algorithms.gSpan.GSpanGeneration.searchEmbeddings(GSpanGeneration.java:213)
```

Comment: your computer needs more ram ?

Comment: Try with lower value of Xmx  say 2048.

Comment: Both previous comments could be right. But you need hard data. I would profile it

Answer (score 0):

try to do it in chunks, maybe because a chunk of code never goes out of scope the memory space is not getting released, in return after a while the operating system steps in, terminates the program and tries to release the memory locations.